# TortoiseSVN client for Windows NT

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am looking for TortoiseSVN client for NT 4.0 system. I know this is outdated but we want to know the right version. Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TorstoiseSVN dropped support for NT all the way back at [1.2.x](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/tsvn_1.2_releasenotes.html).

I don't see 1.1.x on the project's downloads page.

You really need to just move off NT. MS hasn't supported it for a nearly decade.